# Using forms to reload and update a PHP page with jQUERY/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to post info to a PHP page from html inputs and reload it dynamically using jQUERY and AJAX. The function should take all the values from the page inputs and post them to the PHP page, then reload the page in the "graph" div. I have a html page, the script functions I am using, and the PHP page to post to. My function successfully loads the PHP page into the div when my submit button is clicked, but the information I am trying to post doesn't seem to transfer. Help is appreciated.

Here is the jQUERY script I use:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //On-load defaults                     
        var $critSelected = 'sex';     
        $(".criteria#sex").addClass("criteriaSelected");

        //Action for update button
        $('form#update').submit(function() {
            var graphContent = $("#graphContent").attr("value");
            var criteria     = $critSelected;
            var ageLow       = $('#ageLow').attr('value');
            var ageHigh      = $('#ageHigh').attr('value');
            var tr           = $('#tr').attr('checked');
            var ro           = $('#ro').attr('checked');
            var tilch        = $('#tilch').attr('checked');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "graph.php",
                    data: "graphContent="+ graphContent + "criteria=" + criteria,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('div.graph').fadeOut(function(){$('div.graph').load("graph.php").fadeIn();});
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });

        //Change selected criteria
        $(".criteria").click(function() {
            switch($(this).attr("id")) {
                case 'sex':
                    $(this).removeClass("criteriaDeselected").addClass("criteriaSelected");
                    $(".criteria#loc").removeClass("criteriaSelected").addClass("criteriaDeselected");
                    $(".criteria#type").removeClass("criteriaSelected").addClass("criteriaDeselected");
                    $critSelected = 'sex';
                    break;
                case 'loc':
                    $(this).removeClass("criteriaDeselected").addClass("criteriaSelected");
                    $(".criteria#sex").removeClass("criteriaSelected").addClass("criteriaDeselected");
                    $(".criteria#type").removeClass("criteriaSelected").addClass("criteriaDeselected");
                    $critSelected = 'loc';
                    break;
                case 'type':
                    $(this).removeClass("criteriaDeselected").addClass("criteriaSelected");
                    $(".criteria#loc").removeClass("criteriaSelected").addClass("criteriaDeselected");
                    $(".criteria#sex").removeClass("criteriaSelected").addClass("criteriaDeselected");
                    $critSelected = 'type';
                    break;
            }
        });


    });

</script>
```

I grab the posts in the php file like this:

```
   <?php
    include("graphFunctions.php");

    $graphContent = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['graphContent']));
    $criteria     = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['criteria']));
    $ageLow       = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ageLow']));
    $ageHigh      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ageHigh']));
    $tr           = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tr']));
    $ro           = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ro']));
    $tilch        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tilch']));

    echo $graphContent." ".$criteria." ".$ageLow;

    ?>
```

The html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="graph.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <?php include("scripts.php"); ?>

</head>

<body>
<form id="update" method"post">
<div id="leftnav" align="center">

    <div id="title" align="center">
        <select id="graphContent" style="width:150px">
            <option value="Age Distribution">Age Distribution</option>
            <!-- <option value="sex">Sex Distribution</option>
            <option value="volvloc">Volume vs. Location</option>
            <option value="treatment">Treatment Distibution</option> -->
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div id="criteria" align="right">
        <br />
        <div class="criteria" id="sex" style="float:left">&nbsp;&nbsp;By Sex&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="criteria" id="loc" style="float:left">&nbsp;&nbsp;By Location&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="criteria" id="type" style="float:left">&nbsp;&nbsp;In/Out Patient&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div id="constraints" align="left">
        <br />
        Age Range : &nbsp&nbsp;
        <input type="text" value="Low" style="width:30px" id="ageLow" />
        &nbsp;to&nbsp
        <input type="text" value="High" style="width:30px" id="ageHigh" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Location : 
        <input type="checkbox" value="TR" id="tr" />TR 
        <input type="checkbox" value="RO" id="ro" />RO
        <input type="checkbox" value="Tilch" id="tilch" />Tilch<br />
    </div>

    <div class="submit" align="left" style="padding-top:100px">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="graph" style="display:none">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: in your case you dont really need any ajax

Comment: just transfer the data from the form in your graph class, no reload is needed either, and it will be faster

Comment: I'll eventually use the data inside a php function that will draw a graph based on a mysql query.

Comment: ah ok now i get it, so what error are you getting?

Comment: don't understand why you serialize the form data into one value, i'd personaly write each POST parameter separately in the ajax query. Didn't use the method **Nick E.** speaks about in his answer, but that's even nicer I think, shortens JS code well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote your data part of AJAX call, `"graphContent="+ graphContent + "criteria=" + criteria` 
will produce a string like "graphContent=value1criteria=value2", which isn't proper.

What you can do is [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the whole form, using jQuery serialize() method, and send that through:

```
var formData = $('form#update').serialize();
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "graph.php",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('div.graph').fadeOut(function(){$('div.graph').load("graph.php").fadeIn();});
                    }
                });
```

Remember that all form input elements must have a "name" attribute set in order to be serialized by .serialize();

Comment: Ah, one more thing. In the original I wanted to pass the 'criteria variable along with the data from the form data. Any way to add this to the post?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are using jQuery `.load()` to reload the graph. This causes a new instance of the PHP page to be loaded without any `$_POST` parameters!

You already have the page data loaded into the `data` variable. Use something like

```
 $('div.graph').fadeOut(function(){$('div.graph').html(data).fadeIn();});
```

to get the desired result.

---

Also: Do what Nik E says as well ...